# Apache Tika : Settting classpath for opennlp models on tika-server

Tags: apache-tika

I can't seem to set the classpath for the tika-server so that the opennlp models are detected correctly.

I've followed the instructions here:

https://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaAndNER

(substituting app for -server, seen as that looked like it contained everything required)

I have created the following folder structure

```
tika
`-- tika-ner-resources
    `-- org
        `-- apache
           `-- tika
              `-- parser
                  `-- ner
                    `-- opennlp
                       |-- ner-location.bin
                       |-- ner-organization.bin
                       `-- ner-person.bin
```

**Running**:

java -classpath tika/tika-ner-resources -jar tika-server-1.18.jar --config /etc/tika-config.xml -enableUnsecureFeatures -h 0.0.0.0

**and issuing** 
{{ curl -v -XPUT --data-binary @test.pdf http://localhost:9998/tika --header "Accept: text/plain" --header "Content-Type: application/pdf"}}

**results in**

INFO going to load, instantiate and bind the instance of org.apache.tika.parser.ner.opennlp.OpenNLPNERecogniser
WARN Couldn't find model from org/apache/tika/parser/ner/opennlp/ner-location.bin using class loader
INFO LOCATION NER : Available for service ? false
WARN Couldn't find model from org/apache/tika/parser/ner/opennlp/ner-organization.bin using class loader
INFO ORGANIZATION NER : Available for service ? false
WARN Couldn't find model from org/apache/tika/parser/ner/opennlp/ner-date.bin using class loader
INFO DATE NER : Available for service ? false
WARN Couldn't find model from org/apache/tika/parser/ner/opennlp/ner-money.bin using class loader
INFO MONEY NER : Available for service ? false
WARN Couldn't find model from org/apache/tika/parser/ner/opennlp/ner-person.bin using class loader
INFO PERSON NER : Available for service ? false
WARN Couldn't find model from org/apache/tika/parser/ner/opennlp/ner-percentage.bin using class loader
INFO PERCENT NER : Available for service ? false
WARN Couldn't find model from org/apache/tika/parser/ner/opennlp/ner-time.bin using class loader
INFO TIME NER : Available for service ? false
INFO org.apache.tika.parser.ner.opennlp.OpenNLPNERecogniser is available ? false
INFO going to load, instantiate and bind the instance of org.apache.tika.parser.ner.regex.RegexNERecogniser
INFO org.apache.tika.parser.ner.regex.RegexNERecogniser is available ? false
INFO Number of NERecognisers in chain 0

The only thing that seems to work is re-packing the jar by adding the contents of the tika/tika-ner-resources directory (i.e. org/blah/blah/*.bin). The curl command then executes without any issues. I've also tried almost every combination of setting the classpath.

Does anyone have any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone else having issues, the following command worked for me by removing the -jar and manually specifying the TikaServerCli class

```
java -classpath tika/tika-ner-resources/:tika-server-1.18.jar  
org.apache.tika.server.TikaServerCli --config /etc/tika-config.xml -enableUnsecureFeatures -h 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: We've put together some examples for common scenarios in tika-docker that may be useful for others. The NER configuration files are [here](https://github.com/apache/tika-docker/tree/master/sample-configs/ner). I've put together a bit of a write up on how to use them [here](https://meikle.io/technology/opensource/apache-tika-docker-examples.html).